# Prevent elements from extending their parent DIV

Tags: html, css

I have two div's, wrapped inside one container div. The bottom div contains a dynamically filled table (with variable width), which determines the overall width of all div's.

In the top div, I want to list several small red blocks (div's or span's or whatever). These red blocks need to take the available horizontal space, but wrap to a new line if they reach the max allowed width.

So this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't make it work. No matter how I CSS the red blocks (small floating div's, or inline-block's), they keep on taking more width than allowed. As a result, all div's become a lot wider than allowed, wider than my table:

[image]

How can I force these red blocks to only use the allowed with, and pick a new line if they run out of space?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Here's a working example that shows the red blocks (which have variable length) next to each other, taking up more width than they are allowed. They need to start on a new line as soon as the table's width is reached.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqobGp?editors=1100#0

```
table td{
  border:thin solid gray;
  line-height:25px;
  padding:0 5px;
}
.div1, .div2 {
  margin-top:15px;
  padding:20px;
  background:white;
  box-shadow:2px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12)
}
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#f1f1f1;
  padding:30px; 
}
.badge {
  line-height:30px;
  background:red;
  min-width:150px;
  color:white;
  margin:5px 10px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  border-radius:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without some code to see what you've attempted it's hard to know what you're doing right or wrong.

Comment: I don't think you can force cells to the next row, without using javascript. You should use divs for the top section.

Comment: It is a really interesting problem if someone like me has a lot of free time ... here is an example to work http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpKmjG?editors=1100#0

Comment: Perfect example you made there. Only thing missing is display:inline-block; for the "badge" class div. I added it to your code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqobGp?editors=1100#0 . As you can see, the red blocks take up more space than the width of the table below. They need to start a second line sooner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my historical experience, you can achieve such behavior using basic HTML tables if you set small width on a parent table element...

So: for your code, we can use `display: table` and a small `width` on .container and `white-space: nowrap;` for .div2 (to prevent line breaks on table) as following:

```
.container {
  display: table; 
  width: 50px; /* use a small value */
  ...
}

.div2 {
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

here is the [updated code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZGNLx?editors=1100)

Comment: Nice mate just the `display:table`do the trick whit the width and white-space ... note that you mispell the `table-cell` display for the inner divs and you don't need that :) +1

Answer (score 2):

```
/* shrink 2nd div to fit the table */
.div2 {width: fit-content;} 

/* shrink first div to minimum size
 * but constrain it to shrink no further than width established by its siblings
 */
.div1 {min-width: available; width: min-content;}
```

alternative approach

```
.container {width: min-content;}
```

These [width values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Values) are fairly new and [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#width-height-keywords) are still in flux, so different browsers may support them under different names or prefixes may be needed.

Comment: yes, I tested it there. support depends on browser versions and I omitted prefixes for brevity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

Comment: works like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmXNQR?editors=1100#0 @s.serp

Comment: so, you finally add `white-space:nowrap;` css to `.div2` as i suggested in my post. although you didn't mention it in main text of your answer. anyway, thanks

Comment: No, I did not, look at who wrote the comment.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you call your "red" blocks in your css file, but something that is short and simple would be to calculate the width.

For example:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}
.red_block {
  width: calc(100% / 5 - 20px); /* Calculate width here - where it takes the full 100% of the parent and divides it by 5 "red blocks" and subtracts 20px for each */
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

<div class="parent">
    <div class="red_block"></div>
    <div class="red_block"></div>
    <div class="red_block"></div>
    <div class="red_block"></div>
    <div class="red_block"></div>
    <!-- Will wrap to second line -->
    <div class="red_block"></div>
    <div class="red_block"></div>
    <div class="red_block"></div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5s5dodgu/4/)**

Does this answer your question?

**UPDATE:**

With your "red blocks" being calculated via width, you can even specify that class in some media queries to change the width to your liking for mobile devices!  Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
    .red_block {
      width: calc(100% / 3); /* or to whatever you want...IE: width: 100%; */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The red blocks all have a variable length, determined by the text inside. A solution could be to somehow calculate the amount of space we have (width of table), and then tell the red blocks to start a new line if they reach this width... No idea how this is done though...